# Prove with induction: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{>2} \: \exists y\in \mathbb{N}: (n+2)^3 + 2(n+2) = 3y$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I need help to show this proof by induction:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{>2} \: \exists y\in \mathbb{N}: (n+2)^3 + 2(n+2) = 3y$

So far I have "transformed" the universial quantor to a sum symbol:

$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (n+2)^3 + 2(n+2) = 3y$

And then I replaced the $3y$ with $3*\frac{(n+2)^3+2(n+2)}{3}$

As a result I got:

$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (n+2)^3 + 2(n+2) = 3*\frac{(n+2)^3+2(n+2)}{3}$

Then I assumed $n = 3$

$(3+2)^3 + 2(3+2) = 3*\frac{(3+2)^3+2(3+2)}{3}$ 
$135 = 135$

Then: $n = n + 1$ 
$((n+1)+2)^3 + 2((n+1)+2) = 3*\frac{((n+1)+2)^3+2((n+1)+2)}{3}$ 
$((n+1)+2)^3 + 2((n+1)+2) = ((n+1)+2)^3+2((n+1)+2)$

And therefore the equations is true. (?)

I think that I did a mistake here, by thinking that I could replace the Universal Quantifier with a sum symbol. Since I have never done a proof by induction without a sum, I really dont know what to do. Maybe someone could help me and show me a way to proof such equations with Quantifiers in them? Also I am not allowed to use other proofs than a inductive proof.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (n+2)^3 + 2(n+2)=3y$? I ask this because that series diverges.

Comment: I dont know. Since y is dependent from $(n+2)3+2(n+2)$, I think that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(n+2)^3+2(n+2)=3y $

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of divisibility?

Comment: Never had that in my class, so probably not.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the expression $\sum_{n=3}^\infty$?

Comment: Yes, i sum from 3 to infinity. Like a for-loop.

Comment: That's correct. And the sum of all numbers of the form $(n+2)^3+2(n+2)$, with $N$ going from $3$ to $\infty$, is $\infty$. So, it is not $3y$, for some natural number $y$.

Comment: You should not even be attempting a proof using induction without first fully understanding basic FOL (first-order logic). To learn basic FOL, you can try reading "[Language, Proof & Logic](https://homepages.uc.edu/~martinj/Symbolic_Logic/341%20Syllabus,%20Textbook,%20Handouts,%20Notes/LPL%20textbook.pdf)". Mathematics is not about arbitrarily changing some symbols here and there and hoping it makes some sense. Induction is simply "Q(0) ∧ ∀k∈ℕ ( Q(k) ⇒ Q(k+1) ) ⇒ ∀k∈ℕ ( Q(k) )" for every property Q on ℕ. This would be 100% clear once you know basic FOL.

Comment: @Suharick why did you delete https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351009/11206 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think @user21820HATESSMOKING-HATS exaggerates how much you need to formally understand, so let's work with as few symbols as possible. I want you to take this as a guide to how a proof by (weak) induction is supposed to be formatted; that, rather than solving this specific example, is its focus.

**Theorem:** for integer $m\ge5$, some integer $y$ satisfies $m^3+2m=3y$. (My $m$ is your $n+2$, but using $m$ will tidy what we do next.)

**Base case of proof by induction:** I'll leave you to calculate which $y\in\Bbb Z$ works.

**Inductive step of proof by induction:** check if the case $m=k$ works so does the case $m=k+1$, i.e. if $k^3+2k=3y$ then $(k+1)^3+2(k+1)=3(y+z)$ for some integer $z$ (work through the algebra yourself to work out *which* integer). Your stab at the problem didn't verify the increase is thrice an integer; it just wrote an integer as thrice a fraction.

At this point a pedant will argue using a base case $m=5$ isn't what the axiom schema of induction covers, as it's written to use $m=0$. But with $t:=m-5$, we could have stated all this in terms of what's true for integer $t\ge0$; $m$ as I've defined it just makes the algebra simpler for pedagogy. (The "pedant" in this case would know all that, but would want the proof-writer to spell it out properly.) Therefore, I invite you to do a more complicated version starting at $0$.

Of course, we can show $3|m^3+2m$ for all integer $m\ge0$ (or even for arbitrary $m\in\Bbb Z$, but that's another story), so the fact $m=n+2$ appeared in your original problem statement makes me think $\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>2}$ should have been $\forall n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge-2}$. Then the base $m$ would have actually been $0$.

Comment: I dont understand the Inductive step. How can I solve z, if I have two other variables in this equasion? And I dont understand what to do next, when I have calulated z. And why do we take a new integer z and add it to 3y?

Comment: @Suharick The step requires you to work out why one quantity being a multiple of three guarantees the other is, because their difference is a multiple of $3$ too. Simplify$$z=\frac{(k+1)^3+2(k+1)-k^3-2k}{3}$$to verify it's an integer (indeed, it's a polynomial in $k$ with integer coefficients). I could have written the "then" part to write $z$ as an explicit function of $k$ (in which case I needn't have introduced another variable), but it's worth doing some of the work yourself.

Comment: I want to devide my comment in 2 parts:
1. If I try to solve for z I get this results:
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = 3y + z$
<br>
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = (k^3+2k) + z$
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) - (k^3+2k) = z$ 
I dont know what to do so my 
z = (k+1)^3 + 2(k+1) - k^3-2k / 3 

2. I simply took your equasion for z and started to reshape the equasion: 
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = 3 * (y + \frac{(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) - k^3 + 2k}{3})$
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = 3y + (k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) - k^3 + 2k$
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = k^3+2k + (k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) - k^3 + 2k$
$(k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1) = (k+1)^3 + 2 * (k+1)$

Comment: @Suharick Bear in mind it should be $3(y+z)=3y+3z$, not $3y+z$. hence my dividing by $3$ with the rearrangement$$z=(y+z)-y=\frac{(k+1)^3+2(k+1)}{3}-\frac{k^3+2k}{3}=\frac{(k+1)^3+2(k+1)-k^3-2k}{3}.$$You should have found the numerator is $3k^2+3k+3.$

Comment: Thank you! Is my second part correct? I wanted to show that both parts of the equasion are equal. Is this a valid way to show a proof?

Comment: @Suharick As best I can tell, you've again defined a fraction without verifying it's an integer.

Comment: I tried to proof that: 
$3k^2+3k+3$ is divisible by 3 if:
$3k^2+3k+3 = 3y$ 
<br>
$3*(k^2+k+1) = 3y$
<br>
let $y = k^2+k+1$
So $ 3 * (k^2+k+1) = 3 * k^2 + k + 1 $ 

Since a number is multiplied by 3, it is also always divisible by 3 and thus 
$\frac{3k^2+3k+3}{3}$ is an integer.

Comment: @Suharick That sounds fine - a bit long-winded, but valid. You may want to practice how you concisely format & style a full proof by induction, in part by reading other proofs.

Comment: Okay Thank you! So my proof is now complete and correct? Since I showed that $3k^2+3k+3$ is devisible by 3 and an integer. And then showed in my second part, that both equasions are equal. Or am I missing something?